# Helper Functions in C++

Tags: c++

I'm delving into the world of coding and decided to pick up c++ as a starting language.

I came across the topic Helper Functions on a library textbook (name I do not remember) and have been trying to figure it out but I haven't seen much online documentation about it.

As a result I request for the meaning of Helper Functions, the function of this function (*consider this a dad-joke*) and how to implement it in your code, or material that would be helpful towards explaining the use of the topic in question.

It'd be great if this could be dumbed-down as much as possible to that things can be a lot more sizeable to understand.

Comment: i checked through it and it doesn't particularly answer my question.

Comment: A helper function is a function you use in the function which actually does what you want to do; the helper function does something, or computes something which _helps_ you do what you wanted to do in your function. It's not a C++-specific notion.

Comment: information provided seems a bit more advanced with reference to what I believe are arrays in the example explained there. I'm very much still a beginner so i really don't understand a lot of the concepts integrated in the explanation,.

Comment: @JeromeLopez You can ignore the example given in the answer. The paragraphs before it already explain what is usually meant by "helper function" and so do the other answers.

Comment: I would not worry about this so much.  It's not a formal term from the language or anything like    A helper function is just another function.   The word "helper" in front of it is just a synonym for "utility".  It implies it's probably called commonly from many places.  but there is no language-specific requirement or anything. Any function could be a helper function

Comment: Thankyou very much Joe, and everyone else that helped, truly appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @JeromeLopez an helper function is a function you develop in order to improve the main code of your program. Supposing you have a main function which performs some mathematical operations, inside this function you have to compute an integral of a complex function. You can define an helper function which defines the the complex function itself and call it in the main function, in order to don't create a too complex integral function. Did you understand what I mean?